# Pass JSON to aspx webmethod 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I am trying to learn JSON and jQuery and before I delve into anything too complex I thought I would try a simple example to get me up to speed.

I have a button that when clicked I would like to pass a JSON object through to a WebMethod, perform some string operations on it and return to the client side.

However when I click the button nothing happens, the browser console shows the following error:

> POST http://localhost:53388/myfolder/foo/aspx/setrecord 500 (Internal
>   Server Error)

Any help will be greatly appreciated

**jQuery**

```
$('#SaveButton').click(function () {
    var jsonObj = { "data":[{ "id": 1, "name": "Zippy" }, { "id": 2, "name": "George" }, { "id": 3, "name": "Bungle" }, { "id": 4, "name": "geoffrey"}] }
    jsonObj = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
    SaveNewOrder(jsonObj);
})

function SaveNewOrder(jsonObj) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "foo.aspx/setrecord",
        data: jsonObj,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}
function OnSuccess(response) {
    $('#OutputDiv').html(response.d);
}
```

**Classes and WebMethod**

```
public class ListOfDestinationColumns
{
    public List<DestinationColumn> data { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationColumn
{

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
public static string setrecord(string jsonObj)
{
    ListOfDestinationColumns Destinations = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ListOfDestinationColumns>(jsonObj);

    string output = "Start<br/>";
    foreach (var item in Destinations.data)
    {
        output += string.Format("id: {0}, name: {1}<br />", item.id.ToString(), item.name);
    }
    output += "End";
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with a breakpoint on your "setrecord" function to verify that it's actually receiving a valid json?

Comment: A few anomalies. You are telling jQuery that the return value will be json but it looks like a non json string to me. I don't think it is necessary to run JSON.stringify on your submitted data; though this probably doesn't harm. I think your failure handler should be called 'error' and the first param passed to this will be the ajax object - not sure what you want to print here? However; none of that explains why your server code is producing a 500. I think the other posters have suggested the two places for breakpoints?

Comment: @EstebanCervantes I've added a breakpoint in "setrecord" but when I debug and click the save button the breakpoint doesnt get triggered. Does this imply that the webmethod isnt getting called?

Comment: It might help to use the developer console in e.g. Chrome dev tools. Specifically the network tab (with the XHR filter selected perhaps) will show you what was posted where. That would tell you if .net method is being called as you think it is.

Comment: @JustinWyllie done that and it returns the following message under "set record". 

`Message: "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'jsonObj'.",…}
ExceptionType
:
"System.InvalidOperationException"
Message
:
"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'jsonObj'."
StackTrace
:
"   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)
↵   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)`

Comment: @simon-tindall That 500 error indicates that your WebMethod is expecting a parameter named "jsonObj" but is receiving something with a different name. What is the output from your JSON.stringify call?

Comment: @pymaxion the output from JSON.stringify is `{"data":[{"id":"1","name":"Zippy"},{"id":"2","name":"George"},{"id":"3","name":"Bungle"},{"id":"4","name":"geoffrey"}]}`

Comment: Are you still having problems with this? Because after checking your code, I just realized that you're specifying "json" in your content type, but you're sending a string and your server is actually expecting a string as the parameter, so it's highly likely that your method is not being called because the parameters type don't match (also, in dataType you're saying that you're expecting a JSON response from the server, but your function returns a string)